# How to invalidate browser cache programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, invalidation

Long time ago I made a mistake. I created a file for redirect from site root "/" to "/xxx/" for application and forgot add nocache meta.

index.html like

```
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/xxx/">
</head>
</html>
```

Now I have a new app, and I decided to place it in the root, but got big problems. This index.html file cached in users browsers and allways redirects to "/xxx/".

Is it possible to force the browser (from server side or some script) to reload the file. Ctrl+F5 it is impossible to use, because no page loaded. For users manual reset the cache is unreal.

Comment: There are certain pragmas that you can send to _suggest_ to the client to redownload the file from the server rather than using what's in its cache, and most browsers will happily comply. Forcing a client to dump its state against the user's wishes because a strange server requests it? Not likely.

Comment: How to send if no request from browser?

Comment: What?? If there's no request from the browser, there is no cache to invalidate. If you want to make a script that proactively seeks out browsers and invalidates their cache on user machines that aren't even in contact with you, then you're talking about developing a worm.

Comment: Invalidate cache is the first thing that came to mind (that's what I first made by hands). the main task is reload the page in any way and in the future to remove

Answer (score 0):

If you have php on your server, you can try adding this before your script and hope the clients expire their cache:

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
?>
```

but this doesn't guarantee any compliance as the other commenter stated.

Try a redirect from /xxx/ to / using a server side redirect:

```
## /xxx/index.php
<?php
http_redirect("relpath", array("name" => "value"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM);
?>
```

Comment: No requests to the server when user go to root "/", so no request - no response while page in browser cache.

Comment: @andrey.ladniy alright, try adding a redirect from /xxx/ -> / and hope that the client will try to hit the server instead of pulling from cache...

Comment: +1 for showing the correct headers, though I'm torn about suggesting PHP. On the one hand, this isn't tagged PHP. On the other hand, OP didn't mention _any_ relevant server side language so this suggestion is as good as any.

Comment: already tried. in the new application on the common error page "not found" made the link to the root "/", but after click got back to "/xxx/"

Comment: @andrey.ladniy Do not make a link, but make a server redirect. I added it to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yeah, if PHP is installed, it is probably easier than trying to mess with apache mod_cache and such. If this is IIS though, I'm giving all the wrong instructions. ;-)

Comment: @PressingOnAlways ok, i'll try

Comment: not helped. One bowser (with cache invalidated) redirect right to "/", and other to "/" and to "/xxx/"

Comment: how long browser keeps in cache. may be simpler implement other logic in app? Create home page as "/home" and add two server redirects "/" -> "/home" and "/xxx/" to "/home"

Comment: @andrey.ladniy You probably will have to do that. The cache is kept for as long as it is defined by default on the server or by client default settings. If you can open up a developer console in your browser, you can check the Network Response data and look for the exact time in the expires field - ie. expires:Fri, 17 Apr 2015 11:24:56 GMT.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways server redirect bug fixes, but i can not understand which and when ("/"->"/home" or "/xxx/" -> "/home" I have not added anything more). I see "/" request and redirect "/" -> "/home"  in web server logs now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a redirect from "/xxx/" to "/?new".